# Problem with parsing XML file in Groovy script running in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I need to get some data from an XML document in a groovy script running in the Jenkins pipeline. For this, I use `XmlParser()`. The problem is that the code I wrote fully works in Groovy on my machine, but as soon as I run it from Jenkins I get an error.

The Groovy code:

```
@NonCPS
def callTests (String configFile, String pathProjectForAsseration) {

    def configFileAsXML = new XmlParser().parseText(configFile)
    configFileAsXML.testcases.testcase.each { testline ->
        String testFileName = testline['@filename']
        String testEndpoint = testline['@endpoint']
        String testPassword = testline['@password']
        // далее следует логика, не относящаяся к вопросу
    }
}

def runTests() {
    pathToConfigFileForGroovy = "${PATH_TO_CONFIG_FILE}".replace("\\", "/")
    String configFile = readFile(pathToConfigFileForGroovy)
    callTests(configFile, pathProjectForAsseration)
}
```

Example of XML file:

```
<configuration someAttribute="seomeValue">

    <testcases>
        <testcase filename="filename" password="password" login="login"/>
        <testcase filename="filename" password="password" login="login" 
                                                          isReal="false"/>
        <testcase filename="filename" password="password" login="login"/>
        <testcase filename="filename" password="password" login="login" 
                                                          isReal="false"/>
    </testcases>

</configuration>
```

An error occurs on this line:

```
configFileAsXML.testcases.testcase.each { testline ->
```

The error:

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field groovy.util.Node testcases.

Comment: The main SO site is English-only :)

Comment: The XML file example is missing a greater than sign `>`  at the end of the first line.

Comment: Thanks. I accidentally deleted it, along with information relevant to my customer.